# Filtering of objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array result generated by `Promise.All`, it generates more than 2000 objects. I have to categorize each of its object base on its `bch` property. But as I looped over the objects and filter it, the browser always not responding. I checked it and I got a memory leak. I change the way I filter and I got some results but the problem is the other objects fail in being categorized base on `bch` property.

**Here is my javascript**

I got a `$scope.parlist = [];` where I store all the filtered objects.

```
for (let res of results[0]) {
    if ($scope.parlist.length < 1) {
       $scope.eachpar = {
            pdaccounts: [],
            raccounts: [],
            bch: "",
            branch: "",
            pdnoofaccts: "",
            pdamount: "",
            rnoofaccts: "",
            ramount: "",
            par: ""
       }
       $scope.eachpar.bch = res.bch;
       if ($scope.eachpar.bch === "001") {
           $scope.eachpar.branch = "AAA";
       } else if ($scope.eachpar.bch === "002") {
           $scope.eachpar.branch = "BBB";
       } else if ($scope.eachpar.bch === "003") {
           $scope.eachpar.branch = "CCC";
       } else if ($scope.eachpar.bch === "004") {
           $scope.eachpar.branch = "DDD";
       }

       $scope.eachpar.pdaccounts.push({ "acct_name": res.acct_name, "acct_no": res.acct_no, "principal": res.principal });
       $scope.eachpar.raccounts.push({ "acct_name": res.acct_name, "acct_no": res.acct_no, "principal": res.principal_bal });
       $scope.eachpar.pdnoofaccts = 1;
       $scope.eachpar.pdamount = res.principal_bal;
       $scope.eachpar.rnoofaccts = 1;
       $scope.eachpar.ramount = res.principal;

       $scope.parlist.push($scope.eachpar);
    }
    else 
    {

         for (var i = 0; i < $scope.parlist.length; i++) {
              setDelay($scope.parlist,$scope.parlist[i], res);
              //here I set delay
         }
     }
}
```

**Here is my setDelay() function**

```
function setDelay(array,parlisteach,res) {
     setTimeout(function () {
        //I use setTimeout to avoid memory leak
        var obj = array.find(function (obj) { return obj.bch === res.bch; });
        //checking if object with same bch exist in the $scope.parlist
        if (obj !== undefined) {
           if (res.loan_age > 0) {
                parlisteach.pdaccounts.push({ "acct_name": res.acct_name, "acct_no": res.acct_no, "principal": res.principal });
                parlisteach.raccounts.push({ "acct_name": res.acct_name, "acct_no": res.acct_no, "principal": res.principal });
                parlisteach.pdnoofaccts = parlisteach.pdnoofaccts + 1;
                parlisteach.rnoofaccts = parlisteach.rnoofaccts + 1;

                parlisteach.pdamount = parlisteach.pdamount + res.principal_bal;
                parlisteach.ramount = parlisteach.ramount + res.principal;
            } else {
                parlisteach.raccounts.push({ "acct_name": res.acct_name, "acct_no": res.acct_no, "principal": res.principal });
                parlisteach.rnoofaccts = parlisteach.rnoofaccts + 1;
                parlisteach.ramount = parlisteach.ramount + res.principal;
            }
        }
        else
        { //if not exist in $scope.parlist, add it
            $scope.eachpar = {
                pdaccounts: [],
                raccounts: [],
                bch: "",
                branch: "",
                pdnoofaccts: "",
                pdamount: "",
                rnoofaccts: "",
                ramount: "",
                par: ""
            }

            $scope.eachpar.bch = res.bch;
            if ($scope.eachpar.bch === "001") {
                $scope.eachpar.branch = "AAA";
            } else if ($scope.eachpar.bch === "002") {
                $scope.eachpar.branch = "BBB";
            } else if ($scope.eachpar.bch === "003") {
                $scope.eachpar.branch = "CCC";
            }else if ($scope.eachpar.bch === "004") {
                $scope.eachpar.branch = "DDD";
            }

            $scope.eachpar.pdaccounts.push({ "acct_name": res.acct_name, "acct_no": res.acct_no, "principal": res.principal });
            $scope.eachpar.raccounts.push({ "acct_name": res.acct_name, "acct_no": res.acct_no, "principal": res.principal_bal });
            $scope.eachpar.pdnoofaccts = 1;
            $scope.eachpar.pdamount = res.principal_bal;
            $scope.eachpar.rnoofaccts = 1;
            $scope.eachpar.ramount = res.principal;

            array.push($scope.eachpar);

        }

     });
}
```

**This is what I desired result**

```
$scope.parlist = [
    {
        pdaccounts:[{"acct_name":"Test","acct_no":"105451","principal":2000},..],
        raccounts: [{"acct_name":"Test","acct_no":"105451","principal":2000},..],
        "bch": "001",
        "branch": "AAA",
        "pdnoofaccts": 100
        ...
    },
    {
        pdaccounts:[{"acct_name":"Test","acct_no":"105451","principal":2000},..],
        raccounts: [{"acct_name":"Test","acct_no":"105451","principal":2000},..],
        "bch": "002",
        "branch": "BBB",
        "pdnoofaccts": 50
        ...
    },
]
```

I achieve it using my current code but the problem is all the `res` objects goes to the object in `$scope.parlist` with "001" bch and the other `$scope.parlist` objects like "002" has only one item on it. I don't know the error lies in my current code. Please help me.

Comment: I don't know really why using `setTimeout` solves your memory leak, but to filter an array I would probably go with `.filter` method. From what I understand from your code is that you are calling `find` function inside another for loop, seems like very not efficient O(n^2) at least, while `filter` should reduce complexity to O(n)

Comment: when I use the setTimeout it solves the memory leak and I don't know why too. lol

Comment: If you don't know why your code solves a problem I think it is a good starting point to stop and understand your code. please consider using more efficient way of filtering arrays with `filter` as I mentioned above. here is a reference with example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: thank you for your recommendation sir. I will going to consider it.